# Clean up C:\Parallels\Plesk\etc\crashdumps

Tags: windows, iis-7, plesk, crash-dumps, parallels

I'm running Plesk 11.5 on a Windows IIS7 machine.
Because I like to gain more disk space, I want to clean up the Parallels crash-dumps folders:

```
C:\Parallels\Plesk\etc\crashdumps
```

This Folder contains many files like:

```
plesksrv20130126_015742.dmp
```

All this crash-dumps together takes around 500 MB disk space.
Can I delete These crash-dump files simply via windows explorer, or is there a possibility to delete those files via Plesk web interface? Or shouldn't I touch these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete this files via Explorer. There is no way to delete them via Plesk web interface.